# How do we read ‘Charles I’?

Tags: pronunciation

> The lesson had comprised part of the reign of **Charles I**, and
>   there were . . .

How do we read ‘Charles I’?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have to read it aloud, then it's Charles the First.

Comment: And `Charles IV` would be spoken as `Charles the Fourth` etc.

Comment: @Stephen. Yes, it would.

Comment: And `Henry VIII` would be spoken as `Henry the Eighth`, but [sung](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2fbpCUmrTE) as `Henery the Eighth`. :^)

Comment: @J.R. No. It would be 'Enery the Eighth.